# How do I only look at certain rows in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to only look at the information of rows that correspond with 'U' and 'L' and 'R' under the category 'LU'. What exactly do I have to write to grab that specific data?

```
PTYPE   LU
1       E
2       U
3       R
4       L
5       R
```

test = data[data['LU'] == 'U' | 'L' | 'R' ]

I thought it might be the following statement above, but I got an error. 'U' 'L' and 'R' are also not integers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***method 1***
`query`

```
data.query('LU in ("U", "L", "R")')
```

***method 2***
`isin`

```
data[data.LU.isin(list('ULR'))]
```

both result in

[image]

Comment: Is there one better than the other?

Comment: Could also add the more elaborate and versatile `data.loc[data.LU.isin(list('ULR')),'LU']`.